# How can I enumerate over an XDocument?

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML document and I simply want to read each element/node in the document and print it to the console.  Here is my code:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
        var xdoc = XDocument.Load("Items.xml");

        foreach (XNode node in xdoc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Node: " + node);
        }

    }
```

The editor is complaining that `xdoc` is not enumerable.  How can I read each node in the document, if the document isn't enumerable?  Obviously, I'm new to working with XML documents so any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: foreach XNode node in xdoc.Descendants?

Comment: try `xdoc.Descendants()`

Comment: You should probably use `xDoc.Root.Elements`, which will enumerate all the XElements within the root element. Those are easy to deal with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [`Descendants`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.descendants%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
foreach (XNode node in xdoc.Descendants())
{
     Console.WriteLine("Node: " + node);
}
```

Comment: Argh!  I can't believe I missed that.  Thanks so much!  I'll mark the answer as soon as the timer is up.